# Delete remote folder with maven

Tags: maven

I just can't find any example on how to delete a remote directory using maven.
The problem is that prior to doing a deploy on the remote server I would like to delete package for any previously added classes.

I then use the wagon plugin to upload my files like so...

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>upload web.xml</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>upload</goal>
                            </goals>
...
```